# rails and javascript, know if the user has confirmed a dialog

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

In my rails 3.2.17 application, i have a delete button:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', destroy_item_path(@item), 
    method: :delete, 
    data: { confirm: "Do you confirm?"},
    id: "a_delete" 
%>
```

I need to perform some javascript code after the item has been deleted, or better: after the user has confirmed to delete the item.
Naively, i added an id to the anchor and I bound an click listener:

```
$("#a_delete").click(function() {
    //Has the user confirmed or canceled the operation?
} );
```

But how can i know what is the user choice? I've checked the https://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs but I didn't figure out how and even if this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way(after item will destroyed) it's a send request as JS, rails will render destroy.js.erb and you can add code here. Hard way (after confirm before destroy) it's a modify rails confirmation dialog http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2012/07/18/customizing-confirmation-dialog-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having rails.js handle showing the dialog, You can show dialog yourself in your click handler and respond accordingly:

```
$('#a_delete').click(function(e) {
    if(confirm('Do you confirm?') {
        alert('going to delete!');
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('not going to delete!');
    }
} );
```

This will allow you to do your processing before the delete request is sent to the server.

Comment: ok this would of course be a viable solution. the fact that i don't like is to start start using 'frameworks' and then to fall back to sort of 'naive solutions' since farmeworks don't meet the basic requirements or fail to document them

Comment: Do you want to or are restricted to using rails prototype-ujs? If not, it looks like jqueyr-ujs fires an event 'confirm:complete' which sends along the response: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L256

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to switch library each time i found a problem because it's a not a reproducible way of working... what if the new library has a bug? i am worried that i'll end up having each project a different library set

Comment: From my perspective, the rails jquery-ujs is the more popular and maintained of the two and if there was an issue, this project would be more likely to get a timely fix.

Answer (score 0):

Click event occurs before the user can cancel or confirm. You could use a form and capture the submit action, which will only happen after the user confirms, and will not happen at all if the user cancels the dialog.